# Call function to update Context in React Native

Tags: function, react-native, react-context

I am having problems calling a function in React Native.  I simply want to change the value of 'Context'.  Here is some code, first the script for 'context':

```
//LogContext.js

import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const LogContext = React.createContext({
  set: "en",
  login: "false"
})

export const LogContextProvider = (props) => {

  const setLog = (login) => {
    setState({set: "jp", login: login})
  }

  const initState = {
    set: "en",
    login: "false"
  } 

  const [state, setState] = useState(initState)

  return (
    <LogContext.Provider value={state}>
      {props.children}
    </LogContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

and the 'app.js' code:

```
//app.js

import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import { LogContextProvider, LogContext } from './LogContext'

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
const state = useContext(LogContext);

 return (
  <>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Passed config: {JSON.stringify({state})}</Text>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
    </View>
 {state.login === 'false' ? (
        <Button
          title="Go to Login"
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
        />
  )     : (
        <Button title="Stuff" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DoStuff')} />
      )}
  </>
 );

}

function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
const state = useContext(LogContext);

//do stuff to login here...
state.setLog('true');  //not functional...

  return (
      <LogContext.Provider value={'true'}>  //value={'true'} also not functional...   
       <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
         <Text>Login Screen</Text>
         <Button title="Go to Home" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')} />
       </View>
      </LogContext.Provider>
  );

}

function StuffScreen({ navigation }) {
//do other stuff here...
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="DoStuff" component={StuffScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Obviously I am not too familiar with React Native.  Any advice on how to call the "setLog()" function as to enable an update of the value for the 'Context' global variable would be greatly appreciated.  I thank you in advance.

I am trying to modify my "App()" function to wrap the Navigator within the provider as suggested by another user...however this following is completely non-functional...suggestions appreciated:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
const [data, setData] = useState({
set: 'en',
login: 'false',
});

const state = { data, setData };

return (
<LogContext.Provider value={state}>
  <NavigationContainer>
    {state.data.login === 'true' ? (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="BroadCast" component={VideoScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Logout" component={LogoutScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    ) : (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    )}
  </NavigationContainer>
</LogContext.Provider>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is not having a set function in your context and i dont see a need for a separate LogContext provider function.

You can simply do that part in your app.js or whatever the root function. The below example does that. You can see how a state value is passed along with a function to set the values and this can be modified from teh Login component which is inside the provider. If you use a separate provider its a bit confusing. The below is a working example without the navigation part to give you an idea.

```
const LogContext = createContext({
  data: {
    set: 'en',
    login: 'false',
  },
});

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    set: 'en',
    login: 'false',
  });

  const state = { data, setData };

  return (
    <LogContext.Provider value={state}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(state.data)}</Text>
        <Login />
      </View>
    </LogContext.Provider>
  );
}

const Login = () => {
  const state = React.useContext(LogContext);
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        onPress={() => state.setData({ set: 'bb', login: 'true' })}
        title="Update"
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

To modify your code, you should wrap the main navigator inside the LogContext.Provider and maintain the state there which will help you do the rest.
Feel free to ask any further clarification :)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I will attempt to work with this, yes I will likely have some additional questions.  Regards.

Comment: Well I have started playing around with this and have already run into a wall.  Can you please explain "you should wrap the main navigator inside the LogContext.Provider"...?  I have taken all the code within the '<NavigationContainer>' tag and placed it within the '<LogContext.Provider value={state}>' within the "App" function.  Now my application will not boot to any initial screen.  I am also confused why the "data" ('set' and 'login') appear in two locations, at the beginning of the file in "LogContext" and within the "App" function?  Sorry I am new to React Native and find it confusing.

Comment: When you create a context you set a default value and when you create a provider and give a value you will change it, thats whats happening in App

Comment: OK thank you.  So the 'useState' in "App()" that is used to change the value...and according to your provided sample code, this will allow changing of the value in another function...correct?  Also I am confused about your statement about wrapping the 'navigator' inside the 'provider'...please refer to my edited code.  Regards.

Comment: ' this will allow changing of the value in another function' : yes
if you wrap your navigator inside provider you will have access to the context everywhere

Comment: @Pangit check this sample https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/rnn-v5 :)

Comment: OK thanks for that link, I will study it.  Regards.

Comment: This is similar to what you have, if you have any clarifications please ask :)

Comment: Yes it does look similar.  I believe I have accurately replicated my "App()" function based upon that in your link.  I have edited my code above to show the current layout.  I am receiving a separate error however, which is "ReferenceError:  Can't find variable: createContext"...?  Is there some 'import' I am missing?  This appears to originate in the first code block where the "LogContext" is initialized.

Comment: yes you have to import it import React, { useState ,createContext } from 'react';

Comment: I was able to use it without the import by using "React.createContext"...is there a difference?  I believe I am starting to have the structure functional, however where do I place the additional stack.screens for "Home" and "Details"...the way I have it in my edited code above is causing an error...?  Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: There is no difference its all the same, are you still having an error ? you can place screens according to your requirement like a screens folder

Comment: My error seems to do with having multiple '<Stack.Navigator>' tags, do you know how to resolve?  Your sample code you had referenced earlier only seems to deal with 2 'screen' tags dependent on the condition...where do I include the additional 'Stack.Screen' tags within the function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217003/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-pangit).

Comment: I am sorry however after further testing this is not functional.  My "App()" is as appears in my final edit box above.  What is happening is that it seems each screen listed in the 'Stack.Navigate' is rendered sequentially upon the 'login'.  In addition I am still unable to change the 'global' (context) variable.  I am at a complete loss at this point on what to do.  I have been trying for several weeks now to accomplish what is simply done in any other language I am aware by a single statement, "variable = value"...I cannot explain why the simplest concept as this IMPOSSIBLE in React Native.

Comment: Can you create a snack with what you have? i'll check and fix it ?

Comment: Thank you for the offer.  I am going to continue to struggle with it, and depending on how things turn out I will attempt to produce a 'snack'.  Regards and thanks again.

Comment: Hello.  I have this now mostly operative.  I am, however, still unable to change the 'Context' ('global' variable value).  I am at a loss to explain why.  My Snack is [https://snack.expo.io/@pangit/bossy-peach].  The line causing the problem where I am attempting to change the value is currently commented out within that Snack.  Any suggestions you could provide would be HUGELY appreciated.  Regards.

Comment: The snack has errors , can you fix it and bring it to a runnable state ?

Comment: Not sure if I can repair it.  I have never used it before.  There error reported has to do with React Navigation...I would think that should not cause an error...I do not know what to do to repair it...do the 'imports' have some additional special step?  When I run directly on an Android phone there are no errors...other than the problem I am having updating the 'Context'...

Comment: Sure, thank you.  Sorry but I do not understand why the code could run on a physical device but not in the Snack editor.  Thank you in advance for your time.  Regards.

Comment: What exactly is the issue ? from what i see it works as expected
https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/bossy-peach

Comment: did you un-comment the line (in 'VideoScreen') that reads "if (active._test === 1){state.setData({ set: 'bb', login: 'true' })}" ? That is my attempt to change the Context object variables.  This causes some strange behavior, like repeated calls to 'setState'...after about 15 seconds after pressing the 'Submit' button to 'login'...and the 'consoleLog' output also indicates these repeated function calls...

Comment: Yes do it with a button click or a hook like useeffect, you must not update state or context from a functional ccmponent like that, better go through react life cycle hooks and do it, i've updated it using a button and it works fine

Comment: Thanks for your help.  May I ask why when the 'Update' button you added shows an 'Alert' box that seems to indicate the 'fetch' routine (in "Details()") has been run again...?  Is there no way to change the 'context' without a button?  I would prefer it is not dependent upon user action.  Thank you again and regards.

Comment: Also just curious how you got the 'Snack' to work by clearing the problems reported before with 'React Navigation'...?

Comment: You need to read a bit on life cycle methods of react and chose the appropriate one, you can use useEffect hook to perform an action, the snack missed the dependencies so i added them the package.json

Comment: Thanks again for your assistance and time, much appreciated.